# Recurrence relation - equal roots of characteristic equation

Tags: recurrence

I have the following problem:

> Solve the following recurrence relation, simplifying your final answer
> using 'O' notation.
>
> f(0)=3
>
> f(1)=12
>
> f(n)=6f(n-1)-9f(n-2)

We know this is a homogeneous 2nd order relation so we write the characteristic equation: `a^2-6a+9=0` and the solutions are `a1,2=3`.

The problem is when I replace these values I get:

```
f(n)=c1*3^n+c2*3^n
```

and using the 2 initial relations I have:

```
f(0)=c1+c2=3
f(1)=3(c1+c2)=12
```

which gives me that there no values such that `c1` and `c2` such that these 2 relation are true.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the way it should be solved different when it comes to identical roots for the characteristic equation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve it this way, because your matrix A is not diagonalizable.
However, here is what you get if you use Jordan's normal form instead:

```
f(n) = 3^{n-1}(3n + 9)
```

The Jordan matrix and the basis (with notation from wikipedia + Octave) is:

```
J := [3,1;0,3]
P := [3,4;1,1]
```

such that PJP^{-1} = A, where

```
A := [6,-9;1,0]
```

is your recurrence matrix. Furthermore, the Jordan matrix is almost as good as a diagonal matrix for computing powers:

```
J^n = 3^(n-1) * [3,n;0,3].
```

The recurrence is then:

```
[f(n+1); f(n)] = A^n [12,3] = PJ^nP^-1[12,3] = (<whatever>, 3^(n-1)*(3n+9)).
```

Here a quick numerical check (Scala, but you can take whatever you want, Octave or I whatever you like):

```
scala> def f(n: Int): Int = { if (n == 0) 3 else if (n == 1) 12 else (6 * f(n-1) - 9 * f(n-2)) }
f: (n: Int)Int

scala> for (i <- 0 until 20) println(f(i))
3
12
45
162
567
1944
6561
21870
72171
236196
767637
2480058
7971615
25509168
81310473
258280326
817887699
                                                                    ^

scala> def explicit(n: Int): Int = (Math.pow(3, n -1) * (3 * n + 9)).toInt
explicit: (n: Int)Int

scala> for (i <- 0 until 20) println(explicit(i))
3
12
45
162
567
1944
6561
21870
72171
236196
767637
2480058
7971615
25509168
81310473
258280326
817887699
```